# Where can I ask about product licensing?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are licensing questions on- or off-topic on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/are-licensing-questions-on-or-off-topic-on-so)

I am developing software products like WordPress plugins, Magento extensions and software Tools. I would like to know about product licensing.

On which Stack Exchange site would these kinds of questions be appropriate?

Comment: *What* do you want to know about product licensing? That is going to influence whether there is a site for your purpose, and if there is, which one

Comment: @Pekka:I have many question about licencing like is licence can product my product.how to get licence and so on.Thats why i'm asking

Comment: When the duplicate was written, Programmers was not yet out of Beta.  This question is asking where on *SE*, not whether it can be asked on *SO*.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Software licensing is in the [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) over at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

I would ask in their site-specific [Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com) about your specific question if you are not sure (especially if it's directly related to a legal issue that is specific to your locale, as your question may be closed as `"Too Localized"`).