# Do software licensing/legal question belong on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are licensing questions on- or off-topic on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/are-licensing-questions-on-or-off-topic-on-so)

I asked a question regarding licensing of the EASTL library on StackOverflow today and within 20 minutes the question was closed as "off-topic". On the other hand a lot of the questions tagged as "legal" or "licensing" seem to be asking for similar things.

I do understand that ideally a lawyer should answer such questions and that SO is not an ideal place to ask them, however any software developer will sooner or later run into some issue of this kind.

So do software licensing/legal questions belong on StackOverflow?
Maybe we should have LegalOverflow for such things?

Reference:
[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351939/modifying-eastl-and-its-license)
[Questions tagged as 'legal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legal)
[Questions tagged as 'licensing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing)