# why have appstore-approval tag when questions based on that are off-topic

Tags: discussion, tags, off-topic

### What made me ask this question?

Well [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316532/ios-android-store-and-buy-credits-from-outside-respective-stores-no-in-app-purc) got closed saying it is off topic, and I have no problems with it. When I thought about asking that question, my first instinct was it was off-topic and will surely get closed.

But I still asked the question because, I got confused with following tags, and for one moment thought the question might be on-topic after all.

1) [appstore-approval](/questions/tagged/appstore-approval)

And its tool tip says

> Questions marked with this tag concern the approval process of iOS or
>   OS X applications by Apple specialist before adding these applications
>   to App Store.

2) [appstore-approval-process](/questions/tagged/appstore-approval-process)

> Questions about the Apple Appstore app approval Process.

I saw these tags, and there are some questions based on them, many of them are not closed. I know that having a non closed question on a topic doesn't means that kind of questions are welcome here. But why have these tags in first place?

Well, the rest of the story, I asked the question, got one important answer, and promptly got closed. I don't have any complaint/queries about that, and **this thread is not about my question**.

### My question is

What is the point of having those tags I mentioned above? Why aren't they burninated yet?

### Related

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic), somewhat similar , discusses about [license](/questions/tagged/license) tags. And that tag is still there.

Comment: For something to be deleted, it has to be noticed by those who think it should be deleted. Simple as that really.

Comment: @Bart I am not sure I am following what you are saying.. Are u saying questions based on these tags, are so rare that they slip unnoticed?

Comment: Or those active in the tag did not think it was a problematic one. All I'm saying is, we can't observe everything. Sometimes it needs to be brought to our attention explicitly, as you have done now.

Comment: Okay.. got it..