# Burninate the [technical] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

I noticed a strange tag today: [technical](/questions/tagged/technical). With only 44 questions tagged, it seems like an easy one to safely get rid of.

Here are my problems with it:

- There is no good description
- It's used by a variety of questions with totally different foci
- Its general focus seems to *not* deal with programming questions, rather dealing with hardware questions.
- The questions with the technical tag don't even need it to begin with.

It seems like this should be deleted. Is it alright if we (I)  go about retagging this so it will be removed automatically?

Comment: I really would like to know what are the procedure before burninating a tag, any existing question on meta explaining this?

Comment: There's not really an official procedure, as far as I can tell. It's sort of when the community decides a tag is useless, everyone edits the tag out of all the question, then the tag is deleted. At least, to my understanding.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra You could ask that question you know. I did for the [retag requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136805/148672) although the burniate-request [tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) does have some info like don't do it for zero-question tags

Comment: Oh, here's a thought; should [tag:technical-writing] be discarded as well?

Comment: I am +1 for `technical` but -1 for `technical-writing`, since this seems a legit tag in the scope of documentation questions.

Comment: +1 for burning it into the ground. `Technical` seems like the ultimate meta-tag. Aren't all questions on Stack Overflow supposed to be technical in one way or another? ;)

Comment: BTW who deleted the tag? I asked about burninating [another tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163769/why-have-appstore-approval-tag-when-questions-based-on-that-are-off-topic) 2 days ago.. And that tag is still there.. Can I/one can go and retag those questions?

Comment: Is this status-completed?

Comment: Yeah, should be retagged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so here's what I did:

I took the 8 upvotes (at the time) and no negative response as implicit community approval of the burnination, and took half an hour to fix the questions. I figured it would save mods some time. Here's a general breakdown of how this went:

- Many of the questions belonged under [technical-writing](/questions/tagged/technical-writing) as pointed out by Ocaso Protal
- Many of those were about technical books, and were retagged with [books](/questions/tagged/books).
- Many still did not need [technical](/questions/tagged/technical) at all, and it was simply superfluous. For those, the tag was removed.

There were a couple oddballs (there was one flag), but all in all, it went smoothly. The tag should be picked up for deletion in under 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you for the work. One point of critique though. You seem to have mostly simply removed the tag. While useful, tag-removals are also an excellent moment to clean up the overall post. And it seems you have not done so. Next time please address the full post and don't just focus on the single tag.

Comment: Hmm. I did that for a few, but I see your point. I'll bear that in mind from now on, thanks!

Comment: Thanks you for posting the answer and explaining..

Comment: @Bart you have a point, but that may well have drastically increased his 'half an our to fix', in which case he might not even have bothered to start. I'm not sure which is preferable...

Comment: @benjol I am :)